# Unable to add data into firestore collection (Vue | Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I'm unable to add data into a firestore collection named 'products'. I'm not getting any errors in the console but the input values are not being entered into the firestore collection.

This is my AddItems component where the input data will be added into the firestore collection.

```
<template>
  <div class="add-items">
    <h1>Add Items</h1>
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" v-model="name" />
        <textarea placeholder="description" v-model="description"></textarea>
        <input type="text" placeholder="price" v-model="price" />
        <button @click="AddNewItem()">Add Item</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { dbItemAdd } from "../main";

export default {
  name: "AddItems",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      price: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    AddNewItem() {
      dbItemAdd.add({
          name: this.name,
          description: this.description,
          price: this.price,
        })
        .then((docRef) => {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is my main.js file where my firebase is initialized.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

import "../src/assets/main.css";
import firebase from "firebase"; // Your web app's Firebase configuration

// Add the Firebase services that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**********************",
  authDomain: "**************************",
  projectId: "**************************",
  storageBucket: "*************************",
  messagingSenderId: "**********************",
  appId: "***********************************",
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp;

// const fb = firebase;
const dbItemAdd = firebase.firestore().collection("products");
export { dbItemAdd };

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Can you add a `console.log("Adding data to Firestore")` in your `AddNewItem() {..}` function? So we know that the function is actually being called?

Comment: Looks like the code ain't running. I didn't get any response in the console again.

Comment: Are you clicking the button and still the function won't trigger?  Try `@click="AddNewItem`  without `()` and restart your local server instead of hot reload.

Comment: kinda weird but yes

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: that didn't work :(

Comment: Can you confirm firebase is initialized? In `created()` of `AddItems` ? `console.log(firebase.apps)`

Comment: Just did. I'm getting this error: firebase is not defined
    at VueComponent.created (AddItems.vue?14ce:29)

Comment: I got my issue solved. Thanks for your time and effort. I had to just add .prevent to my @click and it worked.